# iOS Safari Mobile: Why is Safari shortly showing the link - instead of canceling the event?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari

I have a JavaScript like that:

```
var nav     = $('#nav_header a');
var current = null;

nav.click( function(event) {
    var key = nav.index($(event.target) );
    if (current != key) {
        // do some fancy stuff
    }
    // works fine on desktop browsers
    event.preventDefault();
    // needed on iOS
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

With this short HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ol id="nav_header" class="nav_header">
        <li><a href="Link 1">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="Link 1">Link 2</a></li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

When I only use `event.preventDefault();` it works fine in all desktop browsers. But on iOS (tested on 5.1) it shows the **address bar** for a short time. When I add `event.stopPropagation();`, too, it stops showing the address bar. But: It still changes the address for a split second but does not load the linked page (as the event is cancelled). Why is this happening and how can I prevent it? I also tried `return false;`, but it has (of course, as expected) the same bevahior as `event.stopPropagation();`.

Comment: What happens if you move `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` to the top of the function? Change the href to #? Use another HTML tag other than A?

Comment: If I were you I would do exactly what Detect said, use rel or rev

Comment: First of all: many thanks for your suggestions. First thing I tried before puttin' it on SO was to place it onto the top (didn't write that in my question) as I thought, that this might be the solution. But that didn't work. So when **adding** a `#` to the links, it stops 'flashing'. But I than loose my JavaScript-turned-off/SEO-fallback, as those anchors really exist. I could change the `href`, when JavaScript is turned on, but I don't feel so good about this, somehow. ;)